# TypeError : undefined is not an object ( _reactNative.Animated.Text.propStyles.style )

Tags: react-native

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SmBx.png)

[image]

Build is successfull, but this happens every time.

Comment: You must provide context to your problem. Blanket statements will often times be ignored. First of all show that you did the work by letting us know what you have tried and what solutions you have tried so far. This is very vague and unclear. Please rework your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PropTypes are no longer in core React Native components](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/03/26/version-0.62#breaking-changes), like Animation.  So, you have to update your dependencies, like `react-native-material-dropdown` and its dependencies.

I have begun this process, but have only published to my forks on github.  You could modify your `package.json` file to something like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "https://github.com/boorad/react-native-material-dropdown",
    ...
  }
```

Warning: it's not a permanent solution.  Ideally, you would want all three repos to have artifacts published to NPM.